# Convert Each Element in List to a Column in a Data Frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list "d":

```
library(combinat)
d = permn(c("a", "b", "c"))
```

This looks as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "a" "b"

[[4]]
[1] "c" "b" "a"

[[5]]
[1] "b" "c" "a"

[[6]]
[1] "b" "a" "c"
```

Is it possible to convert each element of this list into a column?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
desired_result = data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), col2 = c("a", "c", "b"), col3 = c("c", "a", "b"), col4 = c("c", "b", "a"), col5 = c("b", "c", "a"), col6 = c("b", "a", "c"))

 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1    a    a    c    c    b    b
2    b    c    a    b    c    a
3    c    b    b    a    a    c
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `matrix(unlist(d), ncol = length(d))` or, if you need a data frame, `data.frame(matrix(unlist(d), ncol = length(d))` for any length of `d`

Answer (score 2):

We can use a matrix as intermediary step to finally convert to a data.frame, and specifying column names:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(d), ncol = 6)) |>
  setNames(paste0("col", 1:6))
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1    a    a    c    c    b    b
2    b    c    a    b    c    a
3    c    b    b    a    a    c
```